# Method to accept any Enum and return all properties

Tags: java, enums

I have the following Enum where I would like to create a method that will accept an Enum object, and return a comma separated list of the properties of that Enum. So for the following Enum, my method would accept it as a parameter and **return a String of "1, 2"**.

```
 public class typeEnum {
      public enum validTypes{
           TYPE1("1"),
           TYPE2("2");

      private String value;

      validTypes(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static boolean contains(String type) {
        for (validTypes msgType : validTypes.values()) {
            if (msgType.value.equals(type)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
  }
 }
```

My expected method would be something like the following:

```
 public static <E extends Enum<E>, S extends String> String enumPropsToString(E enumClazz, S value) {
 return ....
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't qualify typeEnum as any enum.. Use some interface to "expose" 
 getValue

Comment: What do you intend the second function argument, `S value`, to be used for?

Comment: `S extends String` is useless since String class is final.

Comment: @csunday95 It will be used to clarify the name of the String the value is in, in this Enum, it happens to be `value` but that could change from Enum to Enum

Comment: What do you expect the output to look like?  That's a pretty important piece of information you have not shared.

Comment: @Jim The String returned will be a comma seperated list, in the above enum it would be "1, 2"

Comment: So what happens when the particular enum type doesn't have a `value` member?  You are asking for a generic solution for something that is not generic.  Also, `typeEnum` is not a Java `enum`.  The question is extremely unclear..

Comment: If the enum doesn't have a value member, the developer shouldn't pass it into a method to return its values as a comma-seperated list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enums can implement interfaces:

```
public interface ValuedEnum {
  public String getValue();
}

public class SomeEnum implements ValuedEnum {
  //your body from above
}
```

Then, you can use "intersection types" in your method signature:

```
public <T extends Enum<T> & ValuedEnum> String propsToString (Class<T> enumClass) {
    Arrays.stream(enumClass.getEnumConstants()).map(e -> e.getValue()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

You could also do this via reflection - inspect the `enumClass` parameter of an arbitrary Enum for a `Method` with the `getValue` signature you want, and then reflectively call it; but this way is type-safe and sufficiently trivial that I'd strongly recommend doing this instead.

Reading your comments, if you want to allow an *arbitrary* property, then I'd suggest just using the Stream API:

```
public static <T> String propsToString (T[] values, Function<T, String> extractor) {
    return Arrays.stream(values).map(extractor).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

which can be invoked like this:

```
propsToString(MyEnum.values(), MyEnum::name);
```

Comment: `propsToString(MyEnum.values(), MyEnum::name);` returns "TYPE1, TYPE2" and not the value object "1, 2"

Comment: well, that's because I passed in `MyEnum::name`; you'd replace that with the name of the value you wanted (so `MyEnum::getValue`) for your `getValue` method, `MyEnum::getOtherValue` if you wanted a different value, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the method you need:

```
private static <E extends Enum<E>> String enumValues(Class<E> clazz) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    Method m = clazz.getMethod("values");
    Object[] values = (Object[])m.invoke(null);
    Method f = clazz.getMethod("getValue");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(f.invoke(values[0]).toString());
    for (int i = 1 ; i < values.length ; i++) {
        sb.append(", ");
        sb.append(f.invoke(values[i]).toString());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Usage:

```
enum MyEnum {
    X("A"), Y("B");

    public String value;

    MyEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
// ...
System.out.println(enumValues(MyEnum.class));
// prints "A, B"
```

Explanation of how this works:

Instead of passing an enum instance to the method, you should pass a `Class<E>`. This makes it easier for reflecting stuff from it. It also makes it easier to call the method as you don't need to create a new enum instance.

First, we need to get all the values of the enum class passed in. To do this we get the method `values` from the enum class and call it. Here I stored all the values in a variable called `values`.

I then got the method `getValue` from the enum class. In the comments you said that when an enum does not have a `value` field it should not be passed into this method. I assume you mean you don't care about non-existent `value` fields and you trust the caller. That's why I didn't do any checks here.

After that I used a string builder and for loop to concatenate the value of `value` for each of the enum values.

Phew that was long!

Note that this method is extremely unsafe. You should probably use interfaces like the other answers have said. But hey, this is fun, and you seem confident that you won't pass anything invalid in there. :)